# Typescript const enum alternative

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs, rollupjs, terser

More and more modern Typescript transpilers have moved toward a strategy of per-module transpilation, which significantly increases build speed, but eliminates the possibility for cross-module `const enum` usage, since transpilation of them requires type information.

I have a *significant* amount of `const enums` that when used without the inlining that `const` provides:

1. End up being hundreds of KBs even after minification due to long property names
2. Leak internal, backend property names that I don't want public

Right now I have these `const enum` definitions auto generated from backend native code. As a contrived example, you can imagine I work at Apple and have a great big const enum of every hardware device.

```js
const enum HardwareType {
    Apple1 = 0,
    // ...
    iPhoneX = 412,
    // ...
    iPhoneUltraXD = 499, // Some theoretical unannounced iPhone
}
```

If I just change `const enum HardwareType` to `enum HardwareType`, in addition to bumping up my bundle size, I've now leaked the new "iPhone Ultra XD" to the public.

I see that something like Terser [supports the `--mangle-props` option](https://github.com/terser/terser#cli-mangling-property-names---mangle-props), but even that seems to be warned against in the official docs and also would mean creating a regex that covers every single `HardwareType`? Not to mention that's just my contrived example and I have dozens of these enums in reality with hundreds of values.

I'd really like to use the latest tech for application bundling, but is there really not a better option out there for compile time inlining of constant values?

Comment: I understand the bundle size consideration but you're concern about "leaked" information is misplaced. For one thing `const enum` is for performance not security. For another, security through obscurity is unreliable and poor design.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I don't believe this is security through obscurity. `const enum` actually removes the names during the compilation AFAIK, so unless you have access to the source code, there's no way you can know what does each number mean.

Comment: I'm saying you shouldn't rely on information which is incidentally removed for other reasons, such as performance optimization, as a security feature.

Comment: This is not a security issue. There is no security impact if Apple leaks the name of a new product. There is, however, a product/marketing/user impact of leaking. Additionally, my question is asking for alternatives that _don't_ rely on `const enum`, I'm not trying to defend it. If you have any useful ideas, I'm all ears.

Comment: If all your enums are global, you could theoretically use terser's conditional compilation  api to define each enum member as a global...

Answer (score 0):

`const enum` is not very secure in hiding original names. As you can see in [that playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgMQE6IJZThGAbwCgYyYBBAByoBs4YBeGARgBpTyAhAQzD55MYAJmIBfYsVCRYADyGYceCADpqdOFPDQYATwVZc+Fb378gA) typescript compiler adds original names in comments:

```js
// Input:
const enum Fruites {
    Apple = 1,
    Banana = 2
}

const x = Fruites.Apple
const y = Fruites.Banana

// Output:
"use strict";
const x = 1 /* Apple */;
const y = 2 /* Banana */;
```

If your a really wondering to use the latest tech for application bundling and want to hide some secret names from output files, try to use [esbuild-loader](https://github.com/privatenumber/esbuild-loader) or [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io) itself. It support [define](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#define) option that allows you to replace some secret naming with meaningless values in compilation time like that

```js
define: {
  "secrets.hardwareType.iPhoneUltraXD": "499"
}
```

and safely use the defined value in source code

```js
// Source code: 
if (deviceId === secrets.hardwareType.iPhoneUltraXD) {
// Bundled code:
if(deviceId===499){
```

`define` option could be initiated in webpack or esbuild config file with any computed values (even with required json files) so you have no limit in count of compile-time definitions.